# What is the HOME method?

Tags: methods, process

A client asked me if I knew anything about the HOME development method. I, together with wikipedia and acronymfinder, drew a complete blank.

Has anyone here heard about a development method called HOME?

Comment: Method in what sense? HTTP? You've given no context here.

Comment: he did have it right there in the first sentence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer to this is to follow this link and read the shrt description of the method by the authors themselves.
http://nyttf.dk/?pagetype=book&vareid=44021-1
I can recommend this method as I teach it in project management at a Business Academy for Multimedia Designers i Denmark

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I found that mentioned a HOME development model was [this document on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=m8ekYR9zRQEC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22HOME+development+method%22&source=bl&ots=cyx9_Svtgv&sig=6hUB8EhiZ2m14OX3pXOXy1ZaSDM&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result#PPA1,M1). Apparently, it stands for Holistic, Open Multimedia development Method. But without context, I can't be sure this is right. But my best guess is that if this isn't right, it's another acronym.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your answer by now.

(Developing Multimedia- A Holistic Approach , by Maire Oosterbaan and Louise Harder Fischer)

HOME - holistic open multimedia development method it is a method based on two principles:

1. holistic meaning that all activities are viewed from both a product-oriented and a process-oriented point of view.
2. It is open, meaning it can be adjusted to most developement scenarios and types and products.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of it, either.

I'm sure there's a way for you to garner insight from your client as to what he means.

Perhaps you could ask something like, "In what context are you interested in knowing more about HOME?"